# Exporting a variable in a Tornado class to another module

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, scope, tornado

I'm using the `Tornado framework` and have a `Websockethandler`, which receives data from the client and the value is stored in a variable. How can I send that variable to another module. This is the code (partial):

```
#module a.py

class Handler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):    
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine

    def on_message(self, event):
        data = urlparse.parse_qs(event)
        event= data.get('type')
```

How can the variable `event` be passed to module `b.py`

Thanks

Comment: @NikolayFominyh; I want to pass the value of `event` to another module which interacts with a 3rd party as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Make a function in module `b.py`, for example `on_message` and pass it your `event` variable:

`b.py`:

```
def handle_event(new_event):
    print new_event
```

`a.py`:

```
import b

class Handler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):    
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine

    def on_message(self, event):
        data = urlparse.parse_qs(event)
        event= data.get('type')
        b.handle_message(event)  # this
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go and let you know how I do.

Comment: You could "export a variable" making it global, but that is a bad idea (antipattern - search SO for "global variables")

Comment: I tried the following. But say that `on_message(event)` just prints the argument `event`, then how would I get it to print this in module `b.py`?

Comment: @user1869421, what do you mean by "to print this in module `b.py`"?

Comment: I mean in this example I want the value of event e.g. 'hello' to be printed in the `b.py`

Comment: so, in `b.py` do: `def on_message(event): print event`. Otherwise i don't understand what you want... http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the docs. But I don't think that you can make `event` a cross-module variable.

Comment: I have changed the example in the answer - maybe this will help.